# Weird button outline in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm having an issue with my site on Safari (and on Safari only). If you go to luckyskins.com in Safari and hover over any of the elements in the nav bar, a small outline is left around each button after you stop hovering. This doesn't happen in Firefox or Chrome. Any ideas what this could be?

This is what it looks like when a button is hovered over: http://cl.ly/image/133m0Z3Q3Q2m

And here's what it looks like after the mouse is removed from the button: http://cl.ly/image/1P112U063904

That outline shouldn't be there and doesn't happen on any other browser but Safari. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't replicate - it works in Safari for me. What version and OS are you using?

Comment: That looks like a redraw bug to me.

Comment: I'm using Mountain Lion. It looks like a weird redraw issue to me as well, though I wasn't sure. If that's the case I suppose there's nothing I can do, right? Also, if that's the case, it doesn't seem like it should be an issue for many people and should resolve itself after some update or something.

Answer (score 3):

When styling the button, add the line:

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}
```

That should get rid of it. If it doesn't that is strange.

The * refers to all things that Safari or any browser gives an outline and therefore won't. Add this somewhere in your code and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it. The outline is sporadic as well. Sometimes it will appear on all 4 sides of a button, and sometimes only 3. It almost looks like it's a weird rendering issue, however I've tried it on 2 different machines and have had a few friends try it, all with the same results. Check it out on http://luckyskins.com for yourself.

Comment: That's very strange, I'm not getting any errors. Sorry I couldn't help. I like the iPhone skins you sell thought :)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it only happens on Mountain Lion, so I won't worry too much about it.